# Connecting pygalmesh with PyQt5 for 3D rendering?

Tags: 3d, pyqt, pyqt5, mesh, cgal

I have some pygalmesh-generated meshes with code like:

```
import pygalmesh
s = pygalmesh.Ball([0, 0, 0], 1.0)
mesh = pygalmesh.generate_mesh(s, cell_size=0.2)
```

I would like to render them in a pyqt5 3D viewer window/widget, and navigate in the resulting 3D scene. How can I achieve this?

Is there some simple sample code out there?

Comment: 3D plotting is _hard_, so you probably don't want to do that yourself. I'd just write out the mesh and open it with ParaView, but PV also has a Python API. I'd probably look into this.

Comment: Maybe pygalmesh objects can be converted into some other class (which another lib can I use?) and then rendered directly in a PyQt5 window? Without HDD I/O operations?

Comment: Like I said: ParaView Python API.